# Can't change content-template dynamically

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatemplate

I have a `ContentControl` that I need to set it's `ContentTemplate` dynamically.

so I decided to write 2 `DataTemplates`, and then style my `ContentControl` such that a trigger fires and set the proper template (dt1/dt2) when a Boolean dependency property in my view-model changes (true/false).

But the problem is if the Boolean property is primarily set to `true`, the data template will always be `dt1` and changing the property to `false` wont change the template to `dt2`.

since the data triggers are bound to the Boolean dependency property, shouldn't changing the property result in firing the triggers?

notes:

- There is a button in `MyView` which changes `BooleanDependencyProp` on it's
  click event.
- `MyViewModel` inherits from an interface that
  implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.MyView">
...

<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MyView}, Path=MyViewModel}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BooleanDependencyProp}" Value="true">
                                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <dt1 ... />
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding BooleanDependencyProp}" Value="false">
                                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <dt2 ... />
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You might check out the ContentTemplateSelector property.

Comment: I tried that, but it's the same with templateSelector. it initializes once, and it can't have a dependency property, so i'm not be able to set any bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known shortcoming of the WPF framework, if you want to apply different data templates, consider either using the visual state manager to change the presentation, or swap out the content data template for a user control that changes based on the triggers instead, you'll get more mileage.

There's a lot more I could say, but it would involve knowing your scenario and the differences in these DataTemplates, why you are disambiguating, etc.  Also, MVVM all around? or straight ahead Code+Markup style with a few view models?

Comment: I see, then I'll check out your solutions, thanks. it's MVVM/3Tier with repositories and etc ,also my first wpf application, so i'm not sure whats the best solution in this case. basically i could simply change the templates in the code, but i thought trying pure xaml.

Comment: I would look into using the WPF visual state manager, defining DataTrigger/GoToStateAction pairs.  This is easiest to do using Blend 4